# ¿Cómo enviar correctamente el contenido de un FOREACH() con el método FWRITE()?

Tags: php

Cuando escribes datos en un fichero con el método `fwrite( $p1, $p2)` el segundo parámetro te permite escribir texto plano y variables (cuyo contenido será interpretado). Pero cuando escribes algo que no sea texto o variables, por ejemplo en mi caso un `foreach()` o una `function()`, éste no se interpreta sino que se muestra literal, o peor, da error. Y yo necesito hacer esto y voy a explicar por qué:

.. Intento programar que cuando un usuario inserte texto en una `<textarea>` éste se escriba en un fichero, pero además, que cuando el usuario haga un salto de linea (cuando presione **Enter**), se generen dinámicamente etiquetas `<p></p>` que engloben su texto. 
En el fichero 1 (que es donde tengo la programación para que el usuario escriba en el fichero 2) el siguiente código funciona perfectamente:

```
/*
RECOJO LO QUE EL USUARIO 
ESCRIBE EN LA TEXTAREA
*/
$TEXTAREA = $_POST["textarea"];

/*
1. CONVIERTO EN ARRAY 
LO QUE EL USUARIO ESCRIBE
EN LA TEXTAREA.
2. LOS SALTOS DE LINEA QUE ÉL HAGA
SERÁN LO QUE SEPARE LOS VALORES 
DEL ARRAY
*/
$ARRAY = explode( "\n", $TEXTAREA );

/*
RECORRO TODOS LOS VALORES DEL ARRAY
Y LOS IMPRIMO EN PANTALLA
ENVUELTOS EN LAS ETIQUETAS P
*/
foreach ( $ARRAY as $VALUE ) {
  echo "<p>".$VALUE."</p>";
}
```

Como podrán comprobar, el código de arriba funciona perfecto.
El problema ocurre cuando tengo que escribir los párrafos dinámicos en el fichero 2, haciendo uso del `foreach()`, ya que, como comentaba, el segundo parámetro del método `fwrite()` al parecer sólo interpreta variables y NO funciones ni bucles. Pongo un ejemplo de código erróneo:

```
//CODIGO ERROR
$FICHERO = fopen( 'fichero.php', 'w+' );
fwrite( $FICHERO, 

"
foreach ( $ARRAY as $VALUE ) {
  echo '<p>'.$VALUE.'</p>';
}
"
);
/*
El foreach entre comillas o no, igual da error. Si 
lo rodeo de etiquetas <?php ?> el código 
pasa literal al fichero 2, pero no encuentra las 
variables porque no están definidas  
*/
//ESTO TAMBIEN FALLA:
fwrite( 'fichero.php', 
miFuncion( { foreach (...){...} } ) 
);
```

En conclusión, necesito generar párrafos dinámicamente en el fichero 1 y que pasen correctamente interpretados al fichero número 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes que crear un foreach literalmente dentro, sino pasarle el valor ya formateado como string, ten encuenta que el segundo argumento de `fwrite()` tiene que ser un string cualquier otra cosa resultará en error o en false, por ejemplo puedes utilizar `implode()`:

```
$ARRAY = explode( "\n", $TEXTAREA );
// acumulas en un array
foreach ( $ARRAY as $VALUE ) {
  $data[] = "<p>".$VALUE."</p>";
}

// Unes el array en una cadena de texto
$mi_cadena = implode("", $data);

// ahora ya puedes pasar la cadena a fwrite
$FICHERO = fopen( 'fichero.php', 'w+' );
fwrite( $FICHERO, $mi_cadena );
```

Tambien puedes concatenar dinamicamente un string en el foreach con el operador de asignación sobre concatenación `.=`, ejemplo

```
$ARRAY = explode( "\n", $TEXTAREA );
// defines una variable para ir concatenando
$mi_cadena = '';
// vas concatenando cada "<p>".$VALUE."</p>"
foreach ( $ARRAY as $VALUE ) {
  $mi_cadena .= "<p>".$VALUE."</p>";
}

// ahora ya puedes pasar la cadena a fwrite
$FICHERO = fopen( 'fichero.php', 'w+' );
fwrite( $FICHERO, $mi_cadena );
```

Documentación:

- [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)
- [fwrite()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php)
- [Operadores para strings](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Excelente! Gracias. La forma número dos se me acomoda mejor, es menos código.